# Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

In this opportunity I try to do a simple activity that get a `EditText`, a Button and make an intent when I press the button to call to the number in the `EditText`.

The activity start, but throw an exception like this...

```
01-23 14:41:13.760: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{android.testcall/android.testcall.TestCallActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Tell me if you need more info, or code to view...

code class:

```
public class TestCallActivity extends Activity {
private TelephonyManager _CurrTelephonyManager;
    private PhoneStateListener phoneListener;
    final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvResulState);
    final EditText phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtPhoneNumber);
    private Date lastIdleTime;
    private String currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_IDLE";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testcallactivity);

        phoneListener = new PhoneStateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                switch (state) 
                {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        lastIdleTime = new Date();
                        currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_IDLE";
                    break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK";    
                    break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        currentPhoneState = "CALL_STATE_RINGING";
                    break;
                }
                textview.setText("Phone State: " + currentPhoneState);
            }
        };      
        _CurrTelephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    } catch (Exception error) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    final Button btCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtCallNumber);
        btCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                String uri = "tel:" + phoneNumber.toString().trim() ;
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
}
```

Full error stack:

```
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{android.testcall/android.testcall.TestCallActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.testcall.TestCallActivity.<init>(TestCallActivity.java:21)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-23 15:25:17.234: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Comment: A NullPointerException happens when you try to use a variable without initializing it first. We need more from the Logcat, which shows exactly which class throws it, and the code that throws it.

Comment: Show the entire stack trace. We need to see the innermost exceptions which will show where the null pointer is occurring in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move these in your `onCreate` method after `setContentView`:

```
final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvResulState);
final EditText phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtPhoneNumber);
```

Also, remove the `try`...`catch`. It doesn't do good.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're calling findViewById, it's happening before setContentView.  Move those calls into the onCreate method AFTER the call to setContentView, and your text views won't be null

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to initiate the views before you inflated the XML:

```
final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvResulState);
final EditText phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtPhoneNumber);
```

try to initiate them in your `onCreate()` after the `setContentView()`

```
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.testcallactivity);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TvResulState);
    phoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EtPhoneNumber);

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to initialize _CurrTelephonyManager variable as follows

```
_CurrTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

before the line

```
_CurrTelephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```